# Algorithm in C - who is the winner team

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, data-structures

I need to store data from a tournament. I need to know how many teams will play(n) and the number of games they will play (n!). Then, the team's names and their results. Something like this:

```
Input: 
3 6
TeamX
TeamY
TeamZ
TeamX 0 - TeamY 3
TeamX 1 - TeamZ 0
TeamY 1 - TeamX 0
TeamY 0 - TeamZ 0
TeamZ 0 - TeamX 0
TeamZ 3 - TeamY 1
```

The output will be something like:

```
This winner is TeamY, with 7 point(s)
Won 2 game(s), tied 1 game(s) e lost 1 game(s)
Scored 5 goal(s) e suffered 3 goal(s)
```

---

EDIT2: 
THIS is what I have until now. But it won't work at the scanf.... I can't type the team's names after the number of teams and games. Can you run it and try to understand?

---

Guide: I have game and team structs, first I add team names to theTeams array of structs, then I add the games to the games array of structs. Then, if/else blocks to do the maths of wins, losses, etc and finally see and printf the winner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct game {
  const char *teamA;
  int scoreA;
  const char *teamB;
  int scoreB;
};

struct team {
  const char *teamA;
  int score;
  int wins;
  int losses;
  int ties;
  int scored;
  int suff;

};

struct team team_new(const char *teamA, int score, int wins, int losses, int ties, int scored, int suff)
{
  struct team t;
  t.teamA = strdup(teamA);
  t.score = score;
  t.wins = wins;
  t.losses = losses;
  t.ties = ties;
  t.scored = scored;
  t.suff = suff;

  return t;
};

struct game game_new(const char *teamA, int scoreA, const char *teamB, int scoreB)
{
  struct game g;
  g.teamA = strdup(teamA);
  g.scoreA = scoreA;
  g.teamB = strdup(teamB);
  g.scoreB = scoreB;
  return g;
};

int main(void)
{

  int i, j, teams, nrgames, biggestScore, whichTeam;

  scanf("Teams and number of games %d %d", &teams, &nrgames);

  //add team names to theTeamss struct
  struct team theTeams[teams];
  size_t num_teams = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < teams; ++i)
  {
    char teamA[20];
    if (scanf("%s", teamA) != 1)
      exit(0);
    theTeams[++num_teams] = team_new(teamA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  }


  struct game games[nrgames]; //add games
  size_t num_games = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof games / sizeof *games; ++i)
  {
    char teamA[20], teamB[20];
    int scoreA, scoreB;
    if (scanf(" %s %d - %s %d", teamA, &scoreA, teamB, &scoreB) != 4)
      exit(0);
    games[++num_games] = game_new(teamA, scoreA, teamB, scoreB);
  }


     //run through games[] to change values of theTeams[] scores

  //games - A against B
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof games / sizeof *games; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < sizeof theTeams / sizeof *theTeams; ++j)
    {
      if ((games[i].teamA == theTeams[j].teamA)) //team(A)
      {
        //if A wins
        if(games[i].scoreA > games[i].scoreB)
        {
          theTeams[j].score += 3;
          theTeams[j].wins += 1;
          theTeams[j].scored = games[i].scoreA;
        }
        //if A loses
        else if (games[i].scoreA < games[i].scoreB)
        {
          theTeams[j].score += 0;
          theTeams[j].losses += 1;
          theTeams[j].suff = games[i].scoreB;
        }
        else //tied
        {
          theTeams[j].score += 1;
          theTeams[j].ties += 1;
          theTeams[j].suff = games[i].scoreA;
        }
      }

      if ((games[i].teamB ==  theTeams[j].teamA))//team(B)
      {
        //if B wins
        if(games[i].scoreB > games[i].scoreA)
        {
          theTeams[j].score += 3;
          theTeams[j].wins += 1;
          theTeams[j].scored = games[i].scoreB;
        }
        //if B loses
        else if (games[i].scoreB < games[i].scoreA)
        {
          theTeams[j].score += 0;
          theTeams[j].losses += 1;
          theTeams[j].suff = games[i].scoreA;
        }
        else //tied
        {
          theTeams[j].score += 1;
          theTeams[j].ties += 1;
          theTeams[j].suff = games[i].scoreB;
        }
      }
    }
  }


  //accessing to the winner team
  biggestScore = theTeams[0].score;
  whichTeam = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof theTeams / sizeof *theTeams; ++i){
    if (theTeams[i].score > biggestScore){
      biggestScore = theTeams[i].score;
      whichTeam = i;

    }
  }

  //output
  printf("\n This winner is %s, with %d point(s), Won %d game(s), tied %d game(s) and lost %d game(s), Scored %d goal(s) e suffered %d goal(s)\n", theTeams[whichTeam].teamA, theTeams[whichTeam].score, theTeams[whichTeam].wins, theTeams[whichTeam].losses, theTeams[whichTeam].ties, theTeams[whichTeam].scored, theTeams[whichTeam].suff);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all you need to be able to read and parse the information. As for structures, an actual structure (`struct`) which contains details gathered from the input might be good as well. And learning about pointers and dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 4):

There are no "problems" with C language and strings; you can do whatever you want. It's just a bit more responsibility than in other languages.

You seem to need an array of structures, yes. I would recommend modelling it as just an array of games played, where each game records the teams that took part, and their scores. No need to first record a list of "available" teams, it's easier to just extract that from the game data afterwards.

```
struct game {
  const char *teamA;
  int scoreA;
  const char *teamB;
  int scoreB;
};

struct game game_new(const char *teamA, int scoreA, const char *teamB, int scoreB)
{
  struct game g;
  g.teamA = strdup(teamA);
  g.scoreA = scoreA;
  g.teamB = strdup(teamB);
  g.scoreB = scoreB;
  return g;
}
```

and then in the man program:

```
int main(void)
{
  struct game games[100];
  size_t num_games = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof games / sizeof *games; ++i)
  {
    char teamA[100], teamB[100];
    int scoreA, scoreB;
    if (scanf(" %s %d - %s %d", teamA, &scoreA, teamB, &scoreB) != 4)
      break;
    games[++num_games] = game_new(teamA, scoreA, teamB, scoreB);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is giving me a lot of errors... Also, can you explain with more details the struct part of your code? Thank you

Comment: There is half of the `scanf` call missing in `main`.

Comment: And then it returns g. How do I manipulate it to reach the values I want?

Comment: @MadPat Example: `games[4].scoreA` will read scoreA in the 5th match

Comment: @MadPat The expression `sizeof games / sizeof *games` just evaluates to the length of the array, i.e. 100. And no, as soon as it fails to get the four needed parts it will fail and `break` out of the loop. You should probably use a second variable to keep track, let me edit.

Comment: Can you explain me the for condition (sizeof games / sizeof *games)? Also, struct game games[100] means I have to enter 100 matches?

Comment: I just edited my code up there, I'm having some struggle

Answer (score 1):

C like all programming languages is only as good as the plan you have laid out to model the data

For this, an array of arrays that stores the data can work.

Might want to also consider a database for relationships based on teams. Then you can also add metadata and the like (for example, timestamps). Though its only good if you don't mind externalising application beyond C.

Comment: I'm very confused on how I store the values and manipulate them. My problem here is more of syntax and future algorithm to know who the winner is.

Comment: Looking at the newest edit, are you not getting the numbers into the block of code you wrote?

Comment: Exactly. Because I still need to reach each team of ´struct game g´ to add it to the theTeams struct